# plot a list color data is set by another list

Tags: plotting, color

I have a list of 10 values.
I'm trying to plot the list using ListLinePlot, and using color function set by another list.
The code is:

```
n = 9;
lis = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 1/n}];
grad = {1, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1};
f = Interpolation[grad];
cf = Function[{x, f}, ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 9}}][f]];
ListLinePlot[lis, ColorFunction -> cf]
```

I have tried to set the color data for the values in grad, yet it does not seem to work.
Also how can I plot the x-axis values as in the table?

EDIT - another problem:

I have a problem using interpolation when I'm trying to plot lis to scale.
in this example:

```
n = 10;
lis = Table[i^4, {i, 0, 1, 1/n}];
grad = {1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10};
int = Interpolation[grad];
cf = Function[{x, f}, ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {0, n}}][int[x]]];
cf2 = ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {0, n}}] /@ grad;
g1 = ListLinePlot[lis, ColorFunction -> cf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
g2 = ListLinePlot[lis, ColorFunction -> cf2, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
g3 = ListLinePlot[Table[{i, i^4}, {i, 0, 1, 1/n}], ColorFunction -> cf2, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

g1 is color correctly, and for some reason g2 is not.
when trying to plot the x axis to scale in g3 if I'm using cf it gives me errors for the interpolation function and using cf2 colors it in the wrong way as in g2. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want, but I assume that you want to actually plot `grad` on the y-axis, not `lis`. It also looks like you're trying to get `"AvocadoColors"` to scale from 0 to 9 instead of just the range of the data (1 to 9). If that's the case, my best guess at what you want is this:

```
n = 9;
lis = Subdivide[n];
grad = {1, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1};
cf = Function[{x, f}, ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 9}}][f]];
ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[{lis, grad}],
  ColorFunction -> cf,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

Since `f` is localized in the `Function`, you don't actually use your `Interpolation` in the code so I removed it. The important bit is to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` since you're defining your own scale. Otherwise, it will always try to feed the `ColorFunction` a value between 0 and 1.

You can also define your colours using `Slot`. I find it easier to read myself, but it just depends on what style you prefer.

```
n = 9;
lis = Subdivide[n];
grad = {1, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1};
ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[{lis, grad}], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 9}}][#2] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

For a 2D plot, slot `#1` is x and slot `#2` is f. For 3D plots you have x, y, and f. Some other plots have up to 5 possible numbers that can be delivered to `ColorFunction`. Either way the plot you get is:

[image]

**EDIT 01:**

Hopefully this will be closer to what you were looking for. I used the interpolation as you had it and just call it when I create `cf`.

```
n = 9;
lis = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 1/n}];
grad = {1, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1};
int = Interpolation[grad];
cf = Function[{x, f}, ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 9}}][int[x]]];
ListLinePlot[
  lis, 
  ColorFunction -> cf, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see, lis and grad are of the same size.
I would like to plot lis, I just want that the color function would be set by grad, meaning the graph would be linear as lis, yet the color would be as the values of grad. meaning the graph would be linear, and in the beginning it would be black, then yellow ->green->yellow and black in the end.

Comment: @jonathan I see, it looks like I misunderstood. I've edited my answer. I think it's closer to what you're looking for. The only thing I'm not sure about is if you wanted to leave the x-axis as the numbers 1-10, but that should be easy enough to fix if you wanted something else.

Comment: This helps, I have another question, If grad is long and Interpolation does not work, is there another way to create int[x]? Is there another expression that can replace int[x]?

Comment: @jonathan I don't see why interpolation wouldn't work. I can pretty easily interpolate tens of millions of points so length shouldn't be a problem. You could use the `VertexColors` option of `Line` and create your own graphic. Something like `Graphics[
 Line[
  Transpose[{Range[Length[lis]], lis}],
  VertexColors -> ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {0, 9}}] /@ grad
  ],
 Frame -> True
 ]`

Comment: I have another problem when trying to plot the x-axis to scale, can you look at the EDIT new part in the main question above?

Comment: Hello. I find your EDIT 01 clear and useful. But I have a problem applying it to a data set with multiple lines to be plotted together. For instance, each line has its own `grad`-like color data. How can I write a proper color function for `ListLinePlot`? If one can do this, I feel it could possibly be a solution to [my question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/258237/11125). Any hint would be appreciated and pls feel free to answer the linked question. Thank you!